# AssertionError: Config filename '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/development.ini' does not exist

Tags: ckan

Performing source install from master branch of ckan (e36d471e3daf84a68923f5f6490bbbc7305a9d1c).
Installing DataStore per instructions (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html)

**Execute:**

```
paster --plugin=ckan datastore
```

**Results in error:**

> AssertionError: Config filename
>   '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/development.ini' does not exist.

**The development.ini file is in /etc/ckan/default/, /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ Why is it looking in the wrong directory?**

My ultimate goal is to execute paster datastore set-permissions so I can set the postgres permissions correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to pass the option `-c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini` whenever you run a `paster` command. It does not automatically know the default location of the `development.ini` file. You might find this page in the docs helpful: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/paster.html

Answer (score 0):

you could generate your development.ini like described here:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.1-branch/narr/startup.html
(see middle of page by scrolling down.)

Hth :-)

Comment: I have a development.ini. I used paster and the make-config command. I tried copying that development.ini file to the directory where paster set-permissions command is looking for it, but there were still errors. The problem is something deeper.

Comment: curious. If the file is on the right place it should be found. That's worth a bug report!

Comment: btw: AssertationError seems to be a Unit-Testing-Message !

Comment: tell me what you've done, also if you got it. That sound curious.

Comment: What I've done: I tried to generate postgres permission for the datastore plugin.